# Passing label to method not updating label.text?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label in a winform, and I am trying to pass the label from a start button. Here is my code:

```
public void DirectLinkTask1(string DirectLinkText, string status)
{
    {
        Start(status);
        string url = driver.Url;
        LogIn(status);
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DirectLinkText))
        {
            status = "Waiting for direct link input...";
        }
        driver.Url = $"{DirectLinkText}";
        status = "Direct Link opened, adding to cart...";
        try
        {
            AddToCartDirectLink(DirectLinkText, status);
        }
        catch
        {
            status = "Direct Link Error";
        }
    }
}
```

Button code:

```
string status1 = labelStatus1.Text;
if (TaskTypeBox.Text.Contains("Keyword"))
{
     worker = new BackgroundWorker();
     worker.DoWork += (obj, ea) => KeywordTask1(txtKWDL1.Text, status1);
     worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
else if (TaskTypeBox.Text.Contains("DirectLink"))
{
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (obj, ea) => DirectLinkTask1(txtKWDL1.Text, status1);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
else
{
    labelStatus1.Text = "Please select task type";
}
```

The label isn't updating at all, not sure why. I'm new to C#, and I'm sure it's a simple mistake. It will update to "Please select task type" in the else statement, but that is it. Thank you in advance for the help. please let me know if I can provide anything else to help :)

Comment: Looks like `else` branch never get hit.

Comment: First issue is that when you pass the label text to the task method the argument will never change inside the task method after that, even if the label text is changed. The argument will be a snapshot of what the label said, so nothing will change it inside the while loop.

Comment: Is there a way to change it, so it will be able to change?

Comment: You could pass the label instead of its current text. But it seems like an odd design to use UI-elements for flow control at all. You should look into ”viewmodels”.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to change label text within `BackgroundWorker` then you need introduce `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` eventhandlers

So even BackgroundWorker executing on the different thread those two eventhandlers will be executed on the main thread and will have proper access to the form controls.